# to know next alarm time using setRepeating() method

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent, alarm

I have times like 9:00 AM, 1:00 PM, 7:00 PM, where I set 3 pending intents that are recursively triggered using setRepeating() method every day.

(Here I am saving all these pending intents unique request codes in the local SQLite database)

Here, whenever an alarm is triggered I would like to know the next alarm that is going to be triggered and show to user

Example.. Now an alarm was triggered at 9:00 AM and at this time I should display the user that the next alarm is going to be triggered at 1:00 PM.
Is there any solution that I could get the next alarm details.

Hope I conveyed correctly.If any queries please let me know

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: AlarmManager has a method called getNextAlarmClock(). Did you try that?

Comment: " Gets information about the next alarm clock currently scheduled. The alarm clocks considered are those scheduled by any application using the setAlarmClock(AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo, PendingIntent) method. "----this was mentioned in developer.android.com whereas I am setting alarms using alarmmanager.setRepeating method

Comment: I don't think you will be able to get the next scheduled alarm in any way. What I feel is that you will have to handle them manually.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the other question, you cannot get this information from the AlarmManager. You would need to store the information yourself in a SharedPreferences so that you can refer to it later.

For example, whenever your alarm goes off, you can update the SharedPreferences to indicate when the next repeat should happen.