# setAlarmClock(info,pi); to work as setRepeating()

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent, alarm, repeatingalarm

I used setRepeating() for repeating alarms as per my app requirement. Here, I would also like to know the next alarm that was set using setRepeating() .whereas I couldn't find any of the solutions that give me next alarm time using an alarm that was set with setRepeating(). Even I posted the same question but I got to know that we cant get.(Link here -->)
[how to know next alarm time using setRepeating() method.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47863394/to-know-next-alarm-time-using-setrepeating-method)

whereas somewhere I found we can get next alarm details using  setAlarmClock -

```
alarmManager.setAlarmClock(new AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(date.getTime(),pendingIntent),pendingIntent);

AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo alarmClockInfo= alarmManager.getNextAlarmClock();
```

But the thing is setAlarmClock() is a onetime Alarm setting approach. whereas I need a repeating mechanism.

Correct me if my assumptions are untrue and also somewhere if I am not clear in explaining.

Please suggest me in this regard, will be very thankful for any of your suggestions.

Thanks in Advance

Note: both questions are not same.Because I am asking how could I achieve setRepeating kind of capability in setAlarmClock method.whereas the other post is asking for next alarm capability in the setRepeating method

Comment: Please don't ask the same question multiple times. You can edit your original question, add more relevant information, etc. Asking your question twice is just annoying.

Comment: both questions are not same.Because Iam asking how could I acheive setRepeating kind of capability in setAlarmClock method.whereas the other post is asking for nextalarm capabilty in setRepeating method

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get this information from the `AlarmManager`. You would need to store the information yourself in a `SharedPreferences` so that you can refer to it later.

For example, whenever your alarm goes off, you can update the `SharedPreferences` to indicate when the next repeat should happen.

Comment: I have an array of alarms say..9:00-3days,14:00-2 days,20:00-5 days..where iam setting these using setRepeating() and saving the related info like unique code and duration data into my SQLite db.I am able to acheive till here.My question is when 9:00 alarm strikes  then I should show your next alarm is at 14:00 where I cant get this in setRepeating.But this functionality(get next alarm is in setAlarmClock) .so I was searching whether I have any  repeating mechanism for setAlarmClock....

Comment: There is no way to have repeating alarms using `setAlarmClock()`. The documentation is pretty clear about this.